Triangulation of regular surfaces: why sum of interior angles around a point $=2\pi$
I am looking at the proof of Gauss–Bonnet theorem in pdf, on bottom of page 12, which I dont see why red lined sentence is true.

where $T_j$ is some triangle on the surface.
My try is to start from simple case, if the surface is just a plane, sum of interior angles around a point is certainly $2\pi$
But if the surfaces has some "bending", I'm worrying about the angle sum might be changed. Like sum of interior of triangle in sphere is no longer $\pi$ (although these interior angles are not around same point).
edit:
Re-thinking the way as @Henry comment make sense. Intuitively, for single point we can zoom in, to arbitrary close we like, such that the curvature "vanish"; but for some triangle, no matter how small it is, distance between its vertices cant be 0, it still captures some "bending"
But I am still looking for theorem likes "sum of angle around a point $=2\pi$ on arbitrary surface" to make it concrete.

For a sphere,  the sum of interior angles around a point is also $2\pi$. As you zoom in on a point, you get the same angles as on the tangent plane at that point.

Henry is right. If you think more carefully and formally about how angles on a curved surface are even defined, you will probably decide that the angle between two curves (on the curved surface) that intersect at a point $p$ of the surface really means the angle up on the tangent plane $T_p$ at $p$ between the corresponding tangent (velocity) vectors which "live" inside $T_p$. (But yes, the intuition being that you have a smooth enough surface that when you zoom in a lot you can no longer tell the difference between the surface and its tangent plane.)

@JeppeStigNielsen thx! Resolve back to definition, this become precise and nature.
